# How is the best way to dynamically code uri in php and html?

Tags: php, html

I have a site where every uri is hardcoded.  They have to be replaced.

How's the best way to handle this?  If I use defines the php in the page get a little messy because you have to cat defines outside of echo strings, like:

`echo URL_HOME . "/distribution/getit.php";`

verses using variables

```
echo "$URL_HOME/.....";
```

Now there are two things I know, never ask for an opinion here, and don't use global variables.  So, what's the common coding practice?  Are either of the above correct?

(On some pages where a particular address is used again and again, I'll just build a var on the page and use it there.)

Comment: If OP changed the phrasing of "best way to handle this" to "common ways to handle this", or even "good ways to handle this", and made "what are common coding practices" plural, would that make it less opinion-based? Methinks leaving a comment with a revision pointer would be helpful if a question like this is closed as opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends very much on your site architecture, specifically on how your templating is handled. You could use `$URL_HOME`, but if the templates / other output context have a non-global scope, it's ugly.

For an easy solution, define a constant and use a function to generate your URLs:

```
const URL_HOME = 'http://example.net/';

function make_url($rel_url)
{
    return URL_HOME . $rel_url . '.php';
}
//...
echo make_url('distribution/getit');
```

Here we're adding in `.php` in-function as well, calling the function simply with `'distribution/getit'`. That'll make it easy to modify your URL format later on (e.g. switching to .html extension, /directory/style clean URLs, and/or working with query string rewrites, etc.). You can then tailor all the URLs in one place, instead of concatenating the base URL etc. in multiple locations in your code.

---

One notch up, you can write a class/method(s) to handle your URLs and define the base URL etc. in its properties. You can then also have multiple methods for handling different URLs or URL formats. Here's a basic example. First with static usage, in case you want to keep things short and don't care to create new instances in each scope:

```
class Urls
{
    public static $base = 'http://example.net/';
    public static $ext = '.php';

    public static function make($rel_url)
    {
        return $this->$base . $rel_url . $this->$ext;
    }
}

echo Urls::make('distribution/getit');
// ... http://example.net/distribution/getit.php

Urls::$base = 'http://sub.example.net/'; 
Urls::$ext = '.html'; 

echo Urls::make('distribution/getit'); 
// ... http://sub.example.net/distribution/getit.html
```

If you drop the static mode and instantiate the object, however, you can call it inside strings too:

```
class Urls
{
    public $base = 'http://example.net/';
    public $ext = '.php';

    public function make($rel_url)
    {
        return $this->base . $rel_url . $this->ext;
    }
}

$urly = new Urls();
echo "See here, {$urly->make('distribution/getit')}, the link!";
```

---

Otherwise, if you buffer up your HTML, instead of echoing it out straight away, you could also use tokens, e.g. `{ base_url }distribution/getit.php`, and run a `str_replace('{ base_url }', 'http://whatever', $HTML);` over it before the final output. On a slightly more complex spin on this, use a token such as `{% url:distribution/getit %}`, then run a `preg_replace_callback` in the end, and pipe all matched URL tokens into your URL handler. Nice way to go if you use static HTML templates. (Separating code and presentation is a good idea.)

Comment: These are technically correct options, but IMO I don't see how they're less "messy" than OP's original solution of using a `define` at the top of his page or in an include.

Comment: Using a `define` / `const` would be a fine solution for very basic needs. Op isn't fond of concatenating, however! (I personally don't see why that counts for messy.) These are simply some common options for dealing with URL generation, and they will provide more flexibility down the road when URL schemes are eventually revised. The future revision/rewrite is where OP's approach gets messy.